# C# InputSimulator wrapper - how to use it?

Tags: c#, wrapper, simulator, sendinput

I want to simulate keyboard click for a external program.I've tried SendMessage, PostMessage, SendKeys but they do not send the key to one specific program. So i wanted to try SendInput and i have downloaded a good wrapper for [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

i have added the assembly to my project but i cannot yet start using any of the functions...

What i have to do?
What "Using" should i add?

Comment: "What "Using" should i add". If you use VS, just write in the code InputSimulator and intellisence will suggest you namespaces. Isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need a

```
Using WindowsInput;
```

If that's not it, you can view it in the Object Browser and see the namespace. Just right click the reference in solution explorer and click browse.

Comment: Yes that is it. I tank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate keyboard input to a program like this:

- bring the program you want to send keys to the foreground using **SetForegroundWindow** from **user32.dll**
- use the [SendKeys.SendWait Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) to send the actual key to the program window

Example code (launch notepad before testing):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SendKeyboardInput
{
    public class SendKey
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public void Send()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); //search for process notepad
            if (p.Length > 0) //check if window was found
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle); //bring notepad to foreground
            }

            SendKeys.SendWait("a"); //send key "a" to notepad
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but i managed to do it by following these 3 steps

1. Extract the InputSimulator contents somewhere sensible like your
   project URL
2. In Visual Studio Click Project->Add Reference and browse to the
       InputSimulator DLL file
3. Add the WindowsInput Namespace to the project by adding "using
       WindowsInput;"

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you what using directives you might need, I'm not sure this tool is going to allow you to send input to a specific window.
The "History" section of the page you linked states:

> It was originally written for use in the WpfKB (WPF Touch Screen Keyboard) project to simulate real keyboard entry to the **active** window.

The only solution to this problem I am aware of involves SendMessage, maybe you could further explain where the problem was with that?